# Chemistry 12: Calculating changes in enthalpy

Tags: enthalpy

I was wondering if I could please get some help with this:

> In a coffee-cup calorimeter $\pu{100.0 mL}$ of $\pu{1.0 M}\ \ce{NaOH}$ and $\pu{100.0 mL}$ of $\pu{1.0 M}\ \ce{HCl}$ are mixed. Both solutions are originally at $\pu{24.6 ^\circ C}$. After the reaction, the temperature is $\pu{31.3 ^\circ C}$. Assuming all solutions have a density of $\pu{1.0 g/cm^3}$ and a specific heat capacity of $\pu{4.181 J/(g ^\circ C)}$. What is the enthalpy change for the neutralization of $\ce{HCl}$ by $\ce{NaOH}$?"

This is what I did, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

$$
\begin{align}
q(\text{surroundings}) &= m \cdot c \cdot \Delta T\\
&= \pu{200 g} \cdot \pu{4.184 J/(g ^\circ C)} \cdot (\pu{31.3 ^\circ C} - \pu{24.6 ^\circ C})\\
&= \pu{5.61 kJ}\\[2em]
q(\text{system}) - \pu{5.61 kJ} &= n \cdot \Delta H - \pu{5.61 kJ}\\
&= \pu{0.1 mol} \cdot \Delta H
\end{align}
$$

Thus: $\Delta H = \pu{-56.1 kJ/mol}$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, homework is not welcome here in the forum, which is probably why your question was voted down. However, since you have already given a solution here and only ask for a confirmation, I want to be so nice and reply to your question.

The short answer is: Yes!

In more detail, the following can be said: The heat from the neutralization added to the heat to warm the solution added to the heat to warm the calorimeter has to be equal to zero.

Thus: $Q(\text{neutralization}) + Q(\text{warm the solution}) + Q(\text{warm the calorimeter}) = 0$

In your example, it is assumed for simplicity that the calorimeter does not consume heat to heat up. Therefore $Q(\text{warm the calorimeter}) = 0$.

Thus:

$$
\begin{align}
Q(\text{neutralization}) + Q(\text{warm the solution}) &= 0\\
n \Delta H + m c \Delta T &= 0\\
n \Delta H &= - m c \Delta T\\
\Delta H &= -\frac{m c \Delta T}{n}\\
&= \frac{\pu{200 g} \cdot \pu{4.184 J/(g ^\circ C)} \cdot (\pu{31.3 ^\circ C} - \pu{24.6 ^\circ C})}{\pu{0.1 mol}}\\
&= \pu{-56.1 kJ/mol}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: *"In general, homework is not welcome here in the forum, which is probably why your question was voted down."* This is absolutely not true. The reasons for the downvotes could be many, sloppy formatting, a title without information, not explaining the thought process. The particular cases like this one, i.e. a please check my homework request, however, are not encouraged (and disliked) here, because they hardy ever lead to a good answer, and they are generally to specific to be of future use.